# Cron job starts but doesn't wait to be completed

Tags: linux, ubuntu, backup, cron

I've made a [**tool**](https://github.com/apudiu/server-backup) for backing up website files & DB. It works as expected if ran by any user. Usually it takes around a minute to run in my configuration. When I added it to the cron it starts but exits immediately. If the application experiences any error it loggs in stdout & in the log file, but in this case it logged none.
Found following in `/var/log/cron`

```
Feb  8 20:43:01 test-server CROND[1522301]: (developer) CMD (/mnt/path/to/bin >> /mnt/path/to/exec.log)
Feb  8 20:43:02 test-server CROND[1522299]: (developer) CMDEND (/mnt/path/to/bin >> /mnt/path/to/exec.log)
```

The cron

```
# test cron
47 20 8 * * user /mnt/path/to/bin >> /mnt/path/to/exec.log
```

Contents of `/mnt/path/to/exec.log`

```
[2024-02-08 20:47:01]  Starting backup
```

When it runs correctly it looks like following

```
[2024-02-07 20:13:11]  Starting backup
[2024-02-07 20:13:11] Processing server: 192.168.x.xxx
[2024-02-07 20:13:11] Processing project: 192.168.x.xxx:/path/in/remote/server
[2024-02-07 20:13:11] Processing project: 192.168.x.xxx:/another/path/in/remote/server
[2024-02-07 20:13:25] Processed project: 192.168.x.xxx:/path/in/remote/server
[2024-02-07 20:13:33] Processed project: 192.168.x.xxx:/another/path/in/remote/server
[2024-02-07 20:13:33] Processed server: 192.168.x.xxx
[2024-02-07 20:13:33] ✅ Backup completed
```

How this can be fixed, so the task gets ran correctly?

Comment: I voted to close your question as a duplicate because all typical reasons why Cron jobs fail are explained there. Typical is reliance on $PATH entries and often no useful error handling in the  batch tool / script

Comment: The cron successfully starts your program. Your program prints one line and exits for some reason. So you want someone to debug your program and find out why it exists?

Comment: Thanks @AlexD I've tested my program in every possible way, It works... but only it does  this if run by cron, Same result for root, user & system cron. Do you have any idea about debugging this?

Comment: Questions about debugging are off-topic here.